# Monotouch UIPickerView ValueChange Event for ViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

I want to get event in case `UIPickerView` changes value in any of its component, so that my `UIViewController` can make changes to `Labels`. I have come across only one helpful method provided by `PickerView` model:

```
public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
```

When anything changes, there are corresponding changes reflected in model. But what should I do in case I want to reflect those changes back to `ViewController`? I want to do the job exactly like **Delegates** do in *iOS*. I am not much familiar with c#. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController  
{

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            setupHandlers();
        }

   void setupHandlers()
        {
            pickerModel = new UnitPickerViewModel();
            pickerModel.Items = lengthArray;
            pickerModel.setDataForSecondComponent(lengthArray2);

            pickerView = new UIPickerView();
            pickerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
            pickerView.DataSource = pickerModel;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create weak and strong Obj-C style Delegates:

#### Strong Delegate:

Create a nested `UIPickerViewDelegate` class **within** your `UIViewController` class:

```
    class PickerDelegate : UIPickerViewDelegate
    {
        public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            base.Selected(pickerView, row, component);
            Console.WriteLine(row.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Create and assign the delegate to your `UIPickerView`:

```
var picker = new UIPickerView(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
picker.DataSource = this;
picker.Delegate = new PickerDelegate();
```

#### Weak Delegate:

Skip the nested class and add the UIPicker selected method to your `UIViewController` and tag it with a `Foundation.Export`:

```
[Export("pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:")]
public void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row.ToString());
}
```

Assign your `UIViewController` as the weak delegate:

```
var picker = new UIPickerView(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
picker.DataSource = this;
picker.WeakDelegate = this;
Add(picker);
```